# How to Connect to computer on the workgroup?

Tags: c#

I am trying to connect to a computer over the workgroup. My code is below:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
options.Username = "testusername";
options.Password = "testpwd";
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\19x.16x.x.xx\C$\TestFolder", options);
scope.Connect();
if (scope.IsConnected == true)
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Succeeded", "Alert"); 
} 
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed", "Alert");
}
```

When I run this, I get the exception : "Invalid parameter"

How to sort this out?

edit:

The error is in this line below:

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\19x.16x.x.xx\C$\TestFolder", options);
```

How do we specify the drive? I think the $ is causing the problem

Comment: Cool.  If we knew what line, that would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Per user's comments, OP is trying to do something entirely different than the question implies.  To copy a file from one location to another programmatically one can use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

`File.Copy(sourcePath, destinationPath)`

Where destinationPath is a valid network path.  Over a network, I recommend using a machineName instead of an IP address.  Especially over a VPN where the potential for an IP address to change is high.

`\\machineName\path\filename.csv`

Comment: It's good that you don't get the `Invalid Parameter` exception anymore. Is the new error an exception? Do you indeed have access to the resource you're trying to connect to?

Comment: @sony - You don't have sufficient rights to access WMI.  I think you need admin rights to the client.  It's no longer a programming problem at this point.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your answer. What I am trying to do is connect to a remote server(over VPN . I can manually connect to this server) and do some IO. I am not sure whether this is the way to go.

Comment: WMI is not the right way to go about that.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx.  I need to know more about what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  My initial thought is to direct you to members of the System.IO namespace.

Comment: My scenario is like this : I have my application running in an office. My application need to create CSV files on a remote server at certain times. This remote server is located in a different city and is connected to this machine over VPN. I dont want to map the drive of the server to the machine in the office

Comment: Brain, thanks for your answer. Just one small question: How about authentication? Don't we actually have to login to the server to copy file?

Comment: You may need to run this with elevated priveledges.  One method is to use impersonation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx

Comment: Hi Brian, My login fails while using the identity impersonate

Comment: Try the fully qualified name: domain\username.